# Why output of an integer is different with leading zero

Tags: c++

I am trying to print previously set integer with following code:

```
int n=015;
cout << n;
```

The output I am getting is 13. Why would it be?

Comment: because when there is a leading zero it is in octal not in decimal and shouldn't that be 13?

Comment: If you dont believe him try `int n = 09;` and [watch it not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/659f3ef552e06a37).

Comment: You may want to read more about the c++ syntax [integer_literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)

Comment: The output should be `13`, not `14`.

Comment: @gdlmx: In early versions of C (K&R1, 1978), the digits `8` and `9` were permitted in octal constants. Both `09` and `011` would have had the value `9`. Fortunately that particular misfeature was removed.

Comment: Ohhh....I see its an octal representation.thanks.@bkvnet